# SNORT -Unknown command line checksum option: ascii

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snort

snort -vde -l /var/log/snort -k ascii

when i tried this command it gives me the error

Unknown command line checksum option: ascii.

I don't know why,coz i hve installed snort successfully, and also i did apt-get install ascii,yet no solution. it still exists.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to use the `-K` flag instead of `-k`:

- `-k checksum-mode` valid values: all,  noip,  notcp, noudp,  noicmp,  and  none
- `-K logging-mode` valid values: pcap, ascii, and none

For more details see `man snort`.

Comment: Correct,that was the issue